# Cross Referencing an Item within an Enumerate Display

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, displaystyle

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}
\itemsep3.0em
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3

See also item [referenced \#, in this case \textbf{13}]

\item Item 4
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\item Item 7
\item Item 8
\item Item 9
\item Item 10
\item Item 11
\item Item 12
\item Item 13 (to be referenced).
\item Item 14
\item Item 15
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to reference a specific item number---in the MWE case--**13**

I know that if I wanted to reference a page number, I could do something along the lines of `\pageref{Ref}` and `\label{Ref}`.

QUESTION: Is there, perhaps, an analogous way to make reference to a specific item, so that in the case of the MWE, Latex automatically prints out "See also item **13**"?

Thank you.

Comment: `\label` and `\ref`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic `\label`-`\ref` mechanism works like a charm for items in an `enumerate`-type list.

In the list part of the the document, just write

```
...
\item Item 12
\item \label{item:zzz} Item 13
\item Item 14
...
```

Elsewhere in the document, you'd write

```
... as shown in item \ref{item:zzz} above, ...
```

If you employ the `cleveref` package, you could write

```
... as shown in \cref{item:zzz} above, ...
```

Comment: Many thanks for this most helpful answer.